# Make with Qt Creator : no rule to make target needed by

Tags: qt, compilation, qt-creator, qmake

Using QT Creator I'm having a project (let's call it Proj A) that has a dependency on a static linked project (let's call it Proj B).

Proj A includes some headers needed from Proj B .

In Proj B I removed a header file named "SomeHeader.h" that was used by "MyClass.cpp" from Proj A, and moved the description etc in another header.

Of course in "MyClass.h" from Proj A I removed the old include and replaced it with the new one.

When compiling I get the following error (which honestly baffles me ) :

> make : *** No rule to make target 'SomeHeader.h' , needed by 'MyClass.o' .

I searched compile output, .h , .cpp files , .pro files and 'SomeHeader' cannot be found anywhere.

I've cleaned the projects and rebuilt , still nothing.

I'm guessing QT Creator is making some temporary makefiles that become permanent in some way.

So what should I try next ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow this step should fix your issue :

- Do a build clean
- run qmake again
- enjoy